# Angular 2 How to match Observables data format with Interface

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular2-observables

Basically, the questions is how to change the format of observable returned to the interface format. What I mean is, when I get a data from a database it has a format as: **id, name, img_path, description**. But I want to assign the result to interface:

```
export interface IGallery {
    id: number;
    thumb: string;
    img: string;
    description? : string;
}
```

when I use my service:

```
images:IGallery[];

this._dataService.getEventGallery()
    .subscribe(

      images => { 

        //images 
        this.images = images; <-- how to convert to interface here
        console.log(this.images);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
```

In order to display those images using *ngFor.

Currently I solved like this, but this is not a best solution:

```
.subscribe(

          images => { 

            let result = images;
            let finalArray = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

              console.log(result[i]);
              finalArray.push({thumb: "assets/img/1/events/" + result[i].img_path, img: "assets/img/1/events/" + result[i].img_path, description: result[i].description});
            }

            this.images = finalArray;
            console.log(this.images);


          },
          err => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why we have the [map operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html).

This should do the trick (assuming `getEventGallery()` returns an array, which your code seems to indicate it does):

```
images:IGallery[];

this._dataService
    .getEventGallery()
    .map((images) => {
        return images.map((image) => {
            return {
                thumb: "assets/img/1/events/" + image.img_path,
                img: "assets/img/1/events/" + image.img_path,
                description: image.description
            };            
        });
    })
    .subscribe(

      images => { 

        //images 
        this.images = images;
        console.log(this.images);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
```

Comment: Property 'img_path' does not exist on type 'any[]'.) thats what I keep receiving. Which array or interface I need to use for image in map ?

Comment: @d123546 Oops :) I updated my answer, it should be working now. `Map` expects an array and I was treating it as an object, is why that error appeared.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works perfectly. But can I ask you one more question, regarding mapping. If lets say I want it to be converted in interface, how to write that in map function? I've saw few questions, but didn't manage to find the answer :( Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use casting: `return <IGallery>images.map((image) => {`. Remember interfaces are only used in your editor and during compile time. JavaScript neither knows nor cares about your interfaces. Therefore you'll always have to do the actual transformation of the object yourself.

Comment: Thanks for explanation and help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use map operator.

```
this._dataService.getEventGallery()
.map(images=>images.map(image=>{thumb: "assets/img/1/events/" + image.img_path, img: "assets/img/1/events/" + image.img_path, description: image.description}))
.subscribe(
  images => { 
    this.images = images;
    console.log(this.images);
  },
  err => {
    console.log(err);
  }
);
```